# How to remove jquery json popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Where I am going to add jquery json data in html page.
All HTML page components disappear and only show json data in left top of the page:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', 
    function (data) { 
        document.write('Latitude: ' + data.latitude + '\nLongitude: ' + data.longitude + '\nCountry: ' + data.address.country); 
    }
);
```

Comment: Show your code where you have the issue.

Comment: `$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) { 
document.write('Latitude: ' + data.latitude + 
        '\nLongitude: ' + data.longitude + 
        '\nCountry: ' + data.address.country); 
});`

Comment: Instead of document.Write, try setting these values to some specific div or span elements within your code.

Comment: Think before you ask questions. You might be asking rite but every one must know that. Get rid of minus marks.

Comment: Issuing `document.write()` replaces your current document contents with the one you specified. Don't do that. Instead, as others have suggested, write the contents to a separate, existing `DIV` or `SPAN` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write) for `document.write()` we find this:

> Writes a string of text to a document stream opened by
>   `document.open()`. [...]
> Writing to a document that has already loaded
>   without calling `document.open()` will automatically perform a
>   `document.open` call

... and the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.open) for `document.open()` says:

> The document.open() method opens a document for writing. [...]
> If a
>   document exists in the target, **this method clears it**

Using `document.write()` to inject raw HTML is possibly the most annoying tool to create dynamic documents. You are using jQuery—make use of its DOM manipulation tools.