# example to write json data by jquery with html text

Tags: jquery, html, json

I am beginner in programming, I want someone to give me an example to show me how to write `JSON` data with `HTML` text

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>antar<h2>
        <script>
            $.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {
                document.open();    
                document.write('Latitude: ' + data.latitude + '\nLongitude: ' + data.longitude + '\nCountry: ' + data.address.country);
                document.close();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want the JSON data to be printed in the page?

Comment: <?php echo json_encode(array('test'=>'text1','test2'=>'text2'))?>...this will print the array in json..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add in your html something like:

```
 <h2 id='lat'></h2>
    <h2 id='long'></h2>
    <h2 id='country'></h2>
```

and then refactor your script as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.getJSON('http://api.wipmania.com/jsonp?callback=?', function (data) {

  $("#lat").text(data.latitude);  
  $("#long").text(data.longitude);  
  $("#country").text(data.country);      

});
 });
```

[​Here a working example you can play with](http://jsfiddle.net/65Cbh/).

Comment: Given the OP's [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099969/how-to-remove-jquery-json-popup) I'm pretty sure this is the answer he's looking for.

Comment: @user1939335 It's just an idea/example: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, you can even use other strategy and leverage jQuery too, dig in some doc examples to see how.

Comment: is all the same 
what about this json for example

http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json

Comment: the last example is just more complex, since you have array and you probably want to iterate them: se jQuery.each() function. You probably want to add them in a table

Comment: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <script> jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $.ajax({ url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/102376e7c0e1c995/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json", dataType : "jsonp", success : function(parsed_json) { var location = parsed_json['location']['city']; var temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']; alert("Current temperature in " + location + " is: " + temp_f); } }); }); </script>

that's how to read it ......

Comment: can you type how to make it in table (in answer please)

Comment: @user1939335 you better ask it in another question AFTER writing some code ;)

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.stringify and inject it on any DOM element example with a div with ID `mydiv`

```
var a = JSON.stringify(myJSON);

document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML(a);
```

Reference:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js